# performing a loop operation in SQL server query

Tags: sql-server

I' writing a search function in C# SQL Server, my users can select multiple job groups and this function should check all of the selected group ids in my job table, how can I perform a loop operation in SQL Server? this is my table general schema:

```
id int, jobname varchar, jobgroup int.....
```

I use following query to select my jobs (based on jobgroup):

```
select * from tblJobs where jobgroup='"+userGroups+"'
```

this can be true only when userGroups contains one value, but my users can select several group ids, for instance my userGroups can be something like this: 5,7,10,20 (userGroups can contain much more values)

how should I perform a loop operation in my query so that I can have all matching jobs?
should I concatenate returned values of several queries each selecting one group ID? I think there are better ways

Comment: If you can possibly avoid loops in SQL, do so. The engine is optimized for set operations, not looping, which can really kill performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use looping in SQL - loops tend to kill performance of SQL databases.

In this case, I believe the [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) clause can do:

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tblJobs 
WHERE jobgroup IN ('"+userGroups+"', '"+userGroup2+"')
```

Comment: thanks, can I dynamically create IN phrase? as I don't know what would be my user request

Comment: @Ali_dotNet - You probably don't need to do so dynamically either. Look at [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Comment: thanks Oded but I suppose there is no '=' in this clause, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @Ali_dotNet - No, there isn't. That was a typo - sorry.